# NpgsqlFuzzyStringMatchDbFunctionsExtensions

Tags: npgsql

Can someone please tell me which version of npgsql NpgsqlFuzzyStringMatchDbFunctionsExtensions was added?

I am using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.18 and don't have access to this class.

There are no results for "NpgsqlFuzzyStringMatchDbFunctionsExtensions" on Stack Overflow.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you show the code that you're trying to write? Have you included the reference in the project?

Comment: Thank you for responding, Calculuswhiz. I know that I need to upgrade versions of Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.Postgresql and the http://npgsql.org website says to post in this forum with tag #npgsql for help.
So, I am hoping that someone from npgsql.org can tell me what version I need.

Comment: Still, you'll want to [edit] in details so that whoever is helping you out knows what's going on. Extended discussions should be avoided on Stack Overflow. For example, how do you know you need to update?

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy string matching exists in 3.1, but requires that you reference the [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.FuzzyStringMatch nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.FuzzyStringMatch/) (it was merged into the main package for 6.0, see [this tracking issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1664)).